# Vue JS - How to show or hide an element using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, boolean

I have two radio buttons that accept either true or false, I want to do so that when you click on the radio button named "One" the block appears, and when you click on "No" the block is hidden for this I used this approach

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label
        >One
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="true" v-model="websiteAccept" />
      </label>
      <label
        >No
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          value="false"
          v-model="websiteAccept"
        />
      </label>
      <p>{{ websiteAccept }}</p>
    </div>

    <div v-if="websiteAccept" style="background: yellow">
      <p>Hide / Show block</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      websiteAccept: null,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

But this approach does not work in what, there may be a reason why it does not work if the `websiteAccept` property dynamically changes when you click on the radio buttons

You can also see the given [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-rhodes-f0nxg)

Comment: I think you are assigning the strings “true” and “false” instead of the Boolean primitive values. Try replacing ‘value’ with ‘v-value’ or the short hand ‘:value’: in this way you’ll be passing the actual value that’s inside the quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind your radio button `value` attributes so they are processed as booleans and not strings:

```
   <div>
      <label
        >One
        <input type="radio" name="radio" :value="true" v-model="websiteAccept" />
      </label>
      <label
        >No
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          :value="false"
          v-model="websiteAccept"
        />
      </label>
      <p>{{ websiteAccept }}</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
 <div>
   <div>
     <label
       >On
       <input type="radio" name="radio" :value="true" v-model="websiteAccept" />
     </label>
     <label
       >No
       <input
         type="radio"
         name="radio"
         :value="false"
         v-model="websiteAccept"
         @change="change"
       />
     </label>
     <p>{{ websiteAccept }}</p>
   </div>

   <div v-if="websiteAccept" style="background: yellow">
     <p>Hide / Show block</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
   return {
     websiteAccept: null,
   };
 },
};
</script>
```

Use this  `:value`. This set the value as BOOLEAN, your code set the value as a string.

Comment: what if you have more than 2 choices in the radio group?